# Jenkins : Run specific Maven goal on meeting certain condition

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

I have 3 applications which are integrated with Jenkins.
Now I want to do following tasks on them in Jenkins :

1. After detecting change in SCM, build the application and deploy artifact(jar) to my local Nexus Repository.
2. Do the static code analysis.
3. Deploy the application to UAT server.

Till now, I have been successful in achieving all this requirement.

**Problems:**

I found that

1. I don't need to do static code analysis for every SCM change as it takes around 15mins. It will enough If I perform this action daily once or twice(periodically).
2. I don't need to do update war on UAT for each SCM change, but based on SCM change log(ie if change log contain '#deploy' keyword then upload)

**My not-so-good solution:**

For the time being, I have create 3 different jobs for a one project to fulfill above requirements, which is obviously not a correct thing to do.

So my question is, how can run specific Maven goal based on certain conditions in Jenkins?

Comment: What is the reason you don't want to run code analysis every time?

Comment: We have 3 code analysis plugins: Findbug, PMD and Checkstyle. They takes lots of time.